# How to insert null into an SQL string

Tags: c#, sql-server, string, stored-procedures

In C# code, I have a string that has been concatenated together to build an SQL insert statement, and that is then passed into a stored procedure and run.
The problem is that I have a field in the concatenated string, call it Salary, that is a numeric in the database. However, as it's being built in the C# code, its obviously a string. There's an error in the SP when it comes time to insert, `Error converting data type varchar to numeric`. The big insert string that is created is run in the SP all at once, so I can't check individual values in the SP. And I can't make Salary = the string null, because that just inserts the string "null" rather than a null value.

Comment: Can you paste your code? Usually it will be something like `set @sql = 'select someColumn ' + cast(intColumn as varchar(16)) + ' from sometable'`

Comment: show code instead of describing it please

Comment: First off I have to say please try to use proper SqlCommands and SqlParameters. Secondly, are you putting single quotes around the number?

Comment: You should realize that asking _why my code is not working_ and not providing the code is a bit nonsensical

Comment: if the column is an int column then why would putting null (not inside of "") in the SQL string insert a string of null? [Example](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/insert-statement/insert-null.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some logic in your code like this.

```
if string.IsNullOrEmpty(Salary)
{
    MyParameter = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    MyParameter = int.Parse(Salary);
}
```

Comment: DBNull.Value is not going to work in a string of sql.

Comment: UGH!!! I didn't realize they liked sql injection and were doing it totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyParameter  = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Salary) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Salary;
```